# R: Legend for geom_polygon() with single value

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, r-sp

I'm using ggplot2 for map plots in R. How do I add a legend entry for a layer without a scale, just for a uniform color:

```
geom_polygon(data = watercourses, fill = "#0055aa", alpha = .5)
```

I just want to have the item title "Watercourses" and a color block representing the correct fill color. How does this work? So far, I only figured out how I can include scales to the legend.

Thank you!

EDIT: Here's an example with the NC dataset.

**Map without centroids in legend**

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

demo(nc)

nc_centroids <- st_centroid(nc)

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = BIR74)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = nc_centroids, color = "blue") +
  coord_sf()
```

[image: Map without legend for centroids]

**Wrong usage of `aes()` for legend**

```
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = BIR74)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = nc_centroids, aes(color = "blue")) +
  coord_sf()
```

[image: Wrong usage of aes() for legend]

**Trying to add the centroids to the legend** (based on the answer of r2evans, https://stackoverflow.com/a/75346358/4921339)

```
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = BIR74)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = nc_centroids, aes(color = "County centroids")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Centroids", values = c("County centroids" = "blue"))
  coord_sf()
```

Throws the following messages and an error:

```
Scale for fill is already present.
Adding another scale for fill, which will replace the existing scale.
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

In my original case I use [sp](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.6-0) package instead of [sf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/1.0-9), but the messages and error thrown in the end are the same.

I think I did not yet understand how things work here, unfortunately. Any helping hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place your `fill` in an `aes(.)`, it will create a legend. Since you want a specific color, I suggest also adding `scale_fill_manual`:

```r
ggplot(mtcars[-(1:3),], aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  # placeholder for your `geom_polygon`:
  geom_point(data = mtcars[1:3,], aes(fill = "something"), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "something else", values = c("something" = "#0055aa"))
```

[image: ggplot with single-element legend]

---

Perhaps this to add your blue points:

```r
ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = BIR74)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = transform(nc_centroids, col = "County centroids"), aes(colour = col)) +
  coord_sf() + 
  scale_colour_manual(name = NULL, values = c("County centroids" = "blue"))
```

[image: NC plot with blue centroids and a single-point nameless legend]

---

EDIT by @winnewoerp: Explanation of how it works, for those who have problems understanding it all (like me until now...):

1. Add an extra column to the data frame with a unique value to be used within the legend, this can be done e.g. using the [`transform()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/transform.html) function like in the given example or like `df$col <- "Column unique value"` prior to `ggplot()`.

   The (sole?) advantage to using `transform` is that there is no need to alter the original data, which might affect other processes on it (outside of this image). One *disadvantage* to doing it this way is that one must hard-code the `"Column unique value"` in both the `transform` and the `scale_colour_manual`, below.
2. Use `scale_colour_manual()` to add the legend item (blue colour example):

   ```r
   scale_colour_manual(
     name = "Legend title",
     values = c("Column unique value" = "blue")
   )
   ```

Comment: Thank you, that works! The [`aes()` documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes.html) does not mention this behaviour, or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure ... I just "know" it after working with ggplot2 for a while, legends are made from aesthetics (not just properties, e.g., `color=` _outside_` of `aes(.)`).

Comment: Please see the edit in my question that takes your answer into account.

Comment: You cannot have two calls to `scale_fill_*`. Since you want to manually control one color, you must manually control all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, I still got stuck. It would be awesome if you could "translate" that into R code for the given NC example.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do. Your first scale explicitly identifies a white-to-red gradient, and your second just says `"blue"`. I had initially thought that that was for a single element within your `nc`, but I see that that is not the case. Are you trying to color one county blue why all others are a shade of red? Or something else?

Comment: I try to add a legend symbol for the centroids layer which has a blue dot instead of a light orange one (like in the second example) and has a custom text like "County geographical centres" (not a very useful layer, but it shows hopefully what my intention is). I just do not find out how `aes()` works for such custom legend items.

Comment: See my edit @winnewoerp, perhaps that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! Your solution was absolutely helpful for me and now I finally understood how `scale_colour_manual()` works (and that it has to be used instead of `scale_fill_manual()` here).